# Assigning variable value in dropdown list in table

Tags: php, smarty, smarty2

I have list of Materials as drop down in each row of table (100 rows).
I want to selectively assign any row selected material.

For example, suppose $materialoptions is assigned an array (1=>'Material 1', 2=>'Material 2',3=>'Material 3'). This is list of dropdown in each row.

I want to assign in php say, In row 20, material selected is 'Material 2'.

Below is my implementation. Not able to assign properly.
HTML/Smarty Code

```
<form name='materialsel' id='materialsel' method='POST' action=''>
<table>
{section name=counter start=1 loop=100 step=1}
  <tr>
    <td><SELECT name="materialid_{$smarty.section.counter.index}" id="materialid_{$smarty.section.counter.index}" onchange='return document.forms.materialsel.submit();'><option value='0'>Select Material</option>
 {html_options selected=$material_$smarty.section.counter.index options=$materialoptions}
   </SELECT>
      </td>
 </tr>
{/section}
 </table>
 </form>
```

PHP Code

```
$smarty->assign("materialoptions", array (1=>'Material 1', 2=>'Material 2',3=>'Material 3'));
```

//In row 20, material selected is 'Material 2'

```
$smarty->assign("material_20",2); //Not able to do this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change in your template file

```
{html_options selected=$material_$smarty.section.counter.index options=$materialoptions}
```

into

```
{html_options selected=${"material_{$smarty.section.counter.index}"} options=$materialoptions}
```

But in this case you should probably defined all material_1, material_2 and so on variables because you use them for option creation

**** EDIT ****

You haven't mentioned that you need it in Smarty 2. Smarty 2 doesn't support variable variables so you should rethink of using other way to achieve this.

In PHP instead of

```
$smarty->assign("material_20",2);
```

you should assign variables this way:

```
$selections = array( '20' => 2);        
$smarty->assign("selections", $selections);
```

And in template file you should change

```
{html_options selected=$material_$smarty.section.counter.index options=$materialoptions}
```

into

```
{html_options selected=$selections[$smarty.section.counter.index] options=$materialoptions}
```

Comment: Hello Marcin, {html_options ..... } as above is giving error in PHP  log. PHP Fatal error:  Smarty error: [in modules/materials.html line 51]: syntax error: invalid attribute name: 'material_{$smarty.section.counter.index' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 1547). I am using Smarty 2